# Get list of all subfolders

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, functional-programming, logic

I have a program logic question, how can i get a list of all folders on server :

Lets Say, I have a folder structure as below, and i would like to get a list of all folders inside it :

![enter image description here][1]

```html
String rootDirectory = “Root”; 
CmdClient client = null; 
client.connect("demo.asperasoft.com", "asperaweb", "demoaspera", 22);

// This method gives list of files inside param folder CmdReplyFile cmdfiles=client.execLs(rootDirectory);

//this method gives a list of files 
File[] fileObjects = cmdfiles.getFileList();

//this method gives file count 
int fileCount= cmdfiles.getFileCount();
```

File Class here is not Java file class. Now, when i am trying to print list of all folders, its just giving me :

Alpha
Beta
Gama

```html
private void getFolderList(String rootDirectory) throws IOException, CmdClientException {
        CmdReplyFile cmdfiles=client.execLs(rootDirectory);
        File[] fileObjects = cmdfiles.getFileList();
        for (File fileObject : fileObjects) {
            if (fileObject.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println(fileObject.getName());
                getFolderList(fileObject.getName());
            }
        }
```

Please suggest a possible logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope below code will fulfill your requirement :

```
public void getListOfFolders(String rootPath) {
    List<String> folders = new LinkedList<String>();
    getFolders(rootPath, folders);
    // Now folders got everything you need.
}

public void getFolders(String directoryName, List<String> folders) {
    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : fList) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            folders.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            getFolders(file.getAbsolutePath(), folders);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kartic for response ! Although as i mentioned "File" class is not a Java IO file, its a custom sdk which doesn't have getAbsolutePath method. I am adding snapshot of api's.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that. But you get the logic right?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Kartic ! I was able to do that with your solution :

```
public void getListOfFolders(String rootPath) throws IOException, CmdClientException {
    List<String> folders = new LinkedList<String>();
    folders.add(rootPath);
    getFolders(rootPath, folders);

    for (String items : folders){
        System.out.println("Folders: "+items.toString());
    }
}

public void getFolders(String directoryName, List<String> folders) throws IOException, CmdClientException {
    CmdReplyFile cmdfiles=client.execLs(directoryName);
    File[] fileObjects = cmdfiles.getFileList();
    String dirStructure=folders.get(folders.size()-1).toString();
    for (File file : fileObjects) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            String folderPath=dirStructure+file.getName()+"/";
            folders.add(folderPath);
            getFolders(folderPath, folders);
        }
    }
}
```